# SwiftUI @Binding value can not change and called init

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, publisher

I want to make a picker use SwiftUI, when I change the value in ChildView, it will not change and called ChildView init.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int
    
    init(v: Int) {
        self.value = v
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel(v: 0)
    
    init(value: Binding<Int>) {
        self._value = value
        print("ChildView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("param value: \(value)")
            Text("@ObservedObject bar: \(vm.value)")
            Button("(child) bar.value++") {
                self.vm.value += 1
            }
        }
        .onReceive(vm.$value) { value = $0 }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("(parent) \(self.value)")
            ChildView(value: $value)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I remove `Text("(parent) \(self.value)")` in ContentView, it seems to be normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the described behavior is expected, because source of truth for `value` is in parent, and updating it via binding you update all places where it is used. That result in rebuild parent body, so recreate child view.

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Solution is simple - use state object

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel(v: 0)   // << here !!

   // ... other code
```

**SwiftUI 1.0+**

Initialize view model with updated bound value

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel    // << declare !!

    init(value: Binding<Int>) {
        self._value = value
        self.vm = ViewModel(v: value.wrappedValue) // << initialize !!

    // .. other code
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because anytime `ChildView` gets `init`-ialized - which happens when `ContentView`'s body is recomputed - it create a new instance of `ViewModel` with the value `0`.

Determine first who "owns" the data. If it's some external object, like `ViewModel`, then it should get instantiated somewhere where an instance could be longer-lived, for example in `ContentView` (but it would depend on your real use case):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value = 0
    var childVm = ViewModel(v: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("(parent) \(self.value)")
            ChildView(vm: childVm, value: $value)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    init(vm: ViewModel, value: Binding<Int>) {
        self._value = value
        self.vm = vm
        print("ChildView init")
    }
    // ...
}
```